# web browser authentication

Tags: c#, authentication

I am searching for an idea to solve following problem.

I have coded a C# application with a `web browser`, which shows the administration-page of a small CMS. I wan't to pass the username and password to the page, so that users of the C# Windows application can access the administration-page without typing "username/password"

I have the following idea, which I do not like. The User saves in the Application-Settings "username/password". And every time when the administration-page is loaded, it should be loaded with GET variables. E.g. http://www.mypage.de/administrastion/?user=username&pass=password

But this is not secure enough.

Any ideas, on how I can do it better?

Comment: Yes. Its my CMS. Its PHP MySQL based.

Comment: See if you can get *basic authentication* set up on the PHP side, then figure it out on the C# (hint : it is possible)